# kivy virtual env not working

Tags: python, kivy

I've installed kivy for macOS here http://kivy.org/#download.
I ran the makesymlinks script.

I followed these instructions http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-macosx.html

If I type `kivy` in a terminal, the python console opens, but when I type  `import kivy`, in the kivy python console I get:

> import error no module named app

I also tried in terminal

```
kivy -m pip install kivy
```

but I get:

> Detected Cython version 0.21.2
>       Using this graphics system: OpenGL ES 2
>       Missing GStreamer framework /Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework
>       Missing framework /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework
>       Missing framework /Library/Frameworks/SDL2_ttf.framework
>       Missing framework /Library/Frameworks/SDL2_image.framework
>       Missing framework /Library/Frameworks/SDL2_mixer.framework
>       Deactivate SDL2 compilation due to missing frameworks
>       WARNING: A problem occured while running xcode-select -p (code 2)
>       ....

Comment: When you type 'import kivy' where? Do you run python in the console that the kivy command gave you?

Comment: yes i type import kivy to python console opening after typing kivy to terminal so in kivy virtual env